# Create MongoDB river in Elasticsearch using Java API

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to create using the Java API a new river between MongoDB and ElasticSearch. Using the REST API is pretty easy making a PUT request with the following JSON

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
    "db": "test",
    "collection": "collectionTest"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "testIndex",
    "type": "default"
  }
}
```

But I am having several problems with the Java API. I am trying to use the `CreateIndexRequestBuilder` class but I don't know how to specify the params.

Are they custom params? What about source? I'm pretty lost...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a document with id `_meta` to the `_river` index. The type is the name that you want to give to your index. The document to send is a json containing the configuration needed for your river. Beyond the custom configuration that depends on the river, the json document needs to contain the property `type`, which contains the name used within the river itself to register the `RiverModule`. For the mongodb river it's `mongodb`. The json that you posted is exactly the source that you have to send.

Here is the code that you need:

```
client.index(Requests.indexRequest("_river").type("my_river").id("_meta").source(source)).actionGet();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I want to emphasize that `my_river` is the name of the index to create

Comment: Didn't realize that, I guess that's the case when you don't specify the index object within the configuration.